# Unable to show Error msg on the Order Products

Tags: apex, trigger

i have an order and i want to add products under the order.I dont want user to ad different products in one order.If some tries to add a product that is does not match with the existing product then i want to  show an error  on the Order products.Any insights would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
trigger OrderItemTrigger on OrderItem (before insert, before update) {

     if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert){
        List<Id> oids=new List<Id>();
        for(OrderItem oItem:trigger.new){ 
           if(oItem.OrderId != null)
              oids.add(oItem.OrderId);
        }

       List<Order> Olst=[SELECT Id,ContractId,OpportunityId,Opportunity.Product_Schedules_Calculation__c,
                          (Select Id,PricebookEntryId,PricebookEntry.Name,OrderId FROM OrderItems) from Order where id in:oids];

        system.debug('**Olst===>' +Olst);

        Map<Id,List<OrderItem>> OrderItemMap=new Map<Id,List<OrderItem>>(); 
        List<OrderItem> orderIds=new List<OrderItem>(); 

       for(Order ord:Olst){
          if(ord.OrderItems.size()>0){
              orderIds.addall(ord.OrderItems);
              OrderItemMap.put(ord.id,orderIds);
             }   
        }  
       system.debug('OrderItemMap===>' +OrderItemMap);

       for(OrderItem od:trigger.new){
           Boolean nameError=false;
           if(OrderItemMap.get(od.OrderId)!=null){ 
               for(OrderItem o:OrderItemMap.get(od.OrderId)){
                   if(od.PricebookEntry.Name !=o.PricebookEntry.Name){
                    od.addError('Same order product should be associated with an opportunity.');
                   }
               }
           }


       } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: make sure you are reaching to the line: `od.addError('Same order product shoul...`

Comment: I  debugged it and od.error is executing but error is  not displaying on the Order Product UI

Comment: also use `break;` after the error.

Comment: tried break; but it did not work.

Comment: Your trigger is set to run both Before Insert and Before Update, but it looks like you'd run into an exception on update (because it looks like `List<Id> oid` is only defined for insert operations). You should probably move  `List<Id> oid = new List<Id>();` outside of that if block.

Comment: Also, are you trying to add a new `OrderItem` from the `Order` record, or from an existing `OrderItem`?

Comment: I am trying to insert new OrderItem and i want this piece to only on the insert not on the update.

Comment: `I want show an error on the Order products when a different name product inserted` - this statement is confusing - please [edit] your post and provide an example

Comment: I have edited my question.Let me know if you still need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a specific field to the error. Example:  od.Quantity.addError('Same order product should be associated with an opportunity.');

Comment: Adding it to the record itself seems like a perfectly viable option.

Comment: for mult-line edit products, the error needs to be added to the field, not just the record itself

Comment: You should add a reference to back up that claim, if you can.

Comment: Maybe it only applies to Order Products, but when I added the error just to the record, it would not display. This is the reference that gave me the idea to test it out: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094WUIAY